# a tutorial for making a flexible database for CMS

Tags: php, mysql, database, content-management-system

I want to make one, flexible cms that will serve all my websites without me having to touch the code.
I want it to be very flexible from a forum website thruogh simple CMS to recursive categories tree.

A link to some guide about planning the database and PHP code could be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

A great idea would be to look at some of all the excellent CMS implementation that already exists as open source. How do they do it ? What are the weaknesses and strength with each approach ?

Unless you are doing this to learn - remember that writing a CMS is a solved problem, for any cases I can come up with (in order words - think twice, do you really need to roll your own ?).

Comment: Yes. I found the existing CMS's not flexible enough for my needs.
Please, help me find a tutorial for the database design
(normalize, counld be something like that?)

Answer (score 0):

try www.thetutlage.com , i found some awesome tutorials there like making quiz system and a lot, he also has a video series on cms system in php which is about 30 videos lonng